# Seeking polygon data for Germany's urban areas (metropolitan areas)

Tags: data, germany

I am currently working on a project where I would like to showcase trend differences between rural vs. urban areas in Germany. I am wondering if anyone in this site is able to point me to a resource that would allow me to get the polygons of urban areas (Metropolregionen) in Germany:
In essence the colored areas in this map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Deutsche_Metropolregionen.svg

In essence I would like to map individual lat/long coordinates to either urban or rural.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems as if the map just shows different administrative borders. I would google for "VG_250". There you got a WFS with features for the different administrative borders. Then just select your "rural" and "urban" borders and export them as individual layers and that's it.

I think the "https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/" Servers are down at the moment.